# Increment / decrement vs. additive / subtractive assignment operators?

Tags: objective-c, operators

*Disclaimer: I'm a rather new programming, so this question might be silly.*

In the past, whenever I've wanted to increase or decrease an integer, I would use `integer++` or `integer--`. However, after reading more programming books, I've discovered the operators `+=` and `-=` (which upon further research, I discovered are known as the additive and subtractive assignment operators).

Obviously the assignment operators are most robust as you can vary the amount that you want to increase or decrease an integer by. What I'm wondering is: **are there are any benefits or disadvantages to using `integer++` vs. `integer += 1`?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

integer++ actually does a bit more than you might think.

'++' after an integer first returns the value of integer and then increments integer:

```
int i = 5;
int a = i++; 
//a is now 5
//i is now 6.
i++;
//i iw now 7
```

You can also do ++integer which first increments the integer and then returns the value.

```
int i = 5;
int a = ++i;
//i and a are now 6.
```

As to which operator is better? It comes down to personal preference. Sven points out in the comments that both functions will output nearly identical instructions.

(everything I said is also true for --)

Comment: There is no performance difference for plain integer types. It does matter for complex C++ objects with overloaded operators, because there temporary copies are required.

Comment: Under the hood i++ is slower when the compiler doesn't optimize it away/replaces it for ++i (when applicable). a = i++ actually translates to something like:  tmp = i+1; a = i; i = tmp;. Of course this optimization is easy and always done when possible, so you are partially right :).

Comment: Interesting, I never knew ++i and i++ did different things, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not exactly. On the assembly level this is the same: `a = i++` gets translated to something like `load i to r1, store r1 to a, increment r1, store r1 to i` and `a = ++i` gets translated to `load i to r1, increment r1, store r1 to i, store r1 to a` (with a register `r1` and the memory locations `i` and `a`). The only difference is the order of the increments and stores.

Comment: Great info, now I am assuming you're right, but in programming 101 class I was told that a=i++ was slightly slower because it involved creating an extra variable, but your example just makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I worded my comment a little poorly. Let's try "I never knew ++i and i++ functioned slightly differently".

Answer (score 1):

`++someInteger` and `someInteger += 1` are exactly the same, the first is just a shorter way to write the second. If you use this in an expression there is a difference between `someInteger++` and `++someInteger` though, as Roy T. pointed out.

But you really shouldn’t be thinking about this, just use what feels more natural to you. This certainly doesn’t matter for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just add to this thread... you may also find doing ++integer as opposed to integer++ to be useful (convenient) in some situations.

Note that integer++ or ++integer doesnt make a difference when you use in a for-loop.